# Get NSRunnunigApplication from LSOpenFromURLSpec

Tags: objective-c, pid

ALL,

In order to get the pid of the process I need to have an object of type NSRunningApplication.

I'm launching my application bundle with LSOpenFromURLSpec call.

Is there a way to get an object of NSRunningApplication if the launch is successful?

TIA!!

[EDIT]

So in order to see if I have a bundle I should be writing something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPath isDirectory:YES];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:url];
if( bundle == nil )
{
    printf( "Not a bundle!!";
    return -1;
}
// open the bundle
```

Is this correct? Or there is a better way?

[/EDIT]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the PID of the application process that was launched, after you launch it?

If you can switch to either `-[NSWorkspace openApplicationAtURL:configuration:completionHandler:]` or `-[NSWorkspace openURL:configuration:completionHandler:]`, they directly provide a reference to the `NSRunningApplication` to your completion handler.

Those methods were introduced with the 10.15 SDK. If you need to target earlier versions of macOS, you can use either `-[NSWorkspace launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:]` or `-[NSWorkspace openURL:options:configuration:error:]`. They directly return a reference to the `NSRunningApplication`.

Comment: please see my edit to the OP. I am trying to do some sanity check prior to opening the bundle.

Comment: That seems like a completely separate question. So, open a new one.

Comment: OK. Will open a new one. Thx.

Comment: New question has been created. Thx.